# OR clause affecting an AND clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, or-operator, and-operator

I am creating a SQL statement that searches a database for keywords in specific columns. I need the query to return records that meet criteria for keyword1 AND keyword2. This was working well however I needed to allow the keywords to be queried from multiple columns. After adding the OR Clause have been unable to get the query to return results for records that have a hit for both keywords not just one keyword.

Why is the OR Clause affecting the AND Clause?

How can I revise this statement to allow both of the keywords to be needed to get a hit while also searching the 3 columns specified?

The statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.longdesc IS NULL THEN t1.desc 
WHEN t1.longdesc IS NOT NULL THEN t1.longdesc END AS 'description', 
t1.upc 
FROM Items t1 
LEFT JOIN Suppliers t2 ON t1.supplier = t2.supplier_no 
LEFT JOIN Sections t3 ON t1.Section = t3.section_no 
LEFT JOIN Groups t4 on t1.group = t4.group 
WHERE desc LIKE '%keyword1%' 
OR Item_code LIKE '%keyword1%' 
OR certify_code LIKE '%keyword1%' 
AND desc LIKE '%keyword2%' 
OR Item_code LIKE '%keyword2%' 
OR certify_code LIKE '%keyword2%'
```

Answer (score 3):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. If you want to create a condition which logically says "keyword1 is matched on any of these columns and keywrod2 is matches on any of these columns", you'll need to surround each of `AND`s arguments with parentheses to avoid it taking precedence:

(BTW, the description exression in the select list could be simplified by using `coalesce`)

```
SELECT COALESCE (t1.longdesc, t1.desc) AS description, t1.upc 
FROM Items t1
LEFT JOIN Suppliers t2 ON t1.supplier = t2.supplier_no 
LEFT JOIN Sections t3 ON t1.Section = t3.section_no 
LEFT JOIN Groups t4 on t1.group = t4.group 
WHERE (desc LIKE '%keyword1%' OR 
       Item_code LIKE '%keyword1%' OR 
       certify_code LIKE '%keyword1%') AND 
      (desc LIKE '%keyword2%' OR 
       Item_code LIKE '%keyword2%' OR 
       certify_code LIKE '%keyword2%')
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out a newb!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(t1.longdesc, t1.[desc]) AS 'description'
    , t1.upc 
FROM Items t1 
LEFT JOIN Suppliers t2 
    ON t1.supplier = t2.supplier_no 
LEFT JOIN Sections t3 
    ON t1.Section = t3.section_no 
LEFT JOIN Groups t4 
    on t1.group = t4.group 
WHERE 
    ([desc] LIKE '%keyword1%' 
        OR Item_code LIKE '%keyword1%' 
        OR certify_code LIKE '%keyword1%') 
    AND (desc LIKE '%keyword2%' 
        OR Item_code LIKE '%keyword2%' 
        OR certify_code LIKE '%keyword2%')
```

I cleaned up your case statement to use `ISNULL` instead (`coalesce` would also work), and added parentheses to your where logic.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `WHERE` part to be like below by parenthesizing them using `()`

```
WHERE (
[desc] LIKE '%keyword1%' 
OR Item_code LIKE '%keyword1%' 
OR certify_code LIKE '%keyword1%' 
)
AND 
(
[desc] LIKE '%keyword2%' 
OR Item_code LIKE '%keyword2%' 
OR certify_code LIKE '%keyword2%'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use brackets to make your logic work. See below:

```
 SELECT
  CASE WHEN t1.longdesc IS NULL THEN t1.[desc]
       WHEN t1.longdesc IS NOT NULL THEN t1.longdesc
  END AS 'description',
  t1.upc
 FROM
  Items t1
  LEFT JOIN Suppliers t2
    ON t1.supplier = t2.supplier_no
  LEFT JOIN Sections t3
    ON t1.Section = t3.section_no
  LEFT JOIN Groups t4
    ON t1.[group] = t4.[group]
 WHERE
  (
    [desc] LIKE '%keyword1%'
    OR Item_code LIKE '%keyword1%'
    OR certify_code LIKE '%keyword1%'
  )
  AND (
        [desc] LIKE '%keyword2%'
        OR Item_code LIKE '%keyword2%'
        OR certify_code LIKE '%keyword2%'
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to avoid using `OR` as a performance issue, and use `ISNULL()`, So you can use this:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(t1.longdesc, t1.desc) AS 'description', 
    t1.upc 
FROM 
    Items t1 
LEFT JOIN 
    Suppliers t2 ON t1.supplier = t2.supplier_no 
LEFT JOIN 
    Sections t3 ON t1.Section = t3.section_no 
LEFT JOIN 
    Groups t4 on t1.group = t4.group 
WHERE 
    (desc + ':' + Item_code + ':' + certify_code) LIKE '%keyword1%' 
AND (desc + ':' + Item_code + ':' + certify_code) LIKE '%keyword2%'
```